# Convert individual data set to aggregation in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has unique identifiers such as below

```
Questionnaire id    Age
Q1                      40
Q1                      1
Q1                      7
Q2                     40
Q2                      70
Q2                     30
Q3                     8
Q3                     7
Q3                     4
```

I want to create a categorical variable with the age such as “0-4 years”, ”5 – 14 years”, ” 15-60 years” and “61 and above”.
Then generate a new variable that shows the summary (aggregate) of the data such that the data will look like

```
0-4 years   5-14 years  15-60 years 61 and above years
Q1  1               1              1               0
Q2  0               1              1               1
Q3  1               2              0               0
```

Comment: Use `cut` then `dcast` or `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df$range <- as.vector(cut(df$Age, c(0,4,14,60,Inf)
              , labels = c("0-4", "5-14","15-60","61 and above")))
xtabs(~id+range,df)

    # range
# id   0-4 15-60 5-14 61 and above
  # Q1   1     1    1            0
  # Q2   0     2    0            1
  # Q3   1     0    2            0
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("Q1","Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2","Q2","Q3","Q3","Q3")
       ,Age=c(40,1,7,40,70,30,8,7,4),stringsAsFactors = F)
```